# I import the same header for all pages on the website, how do i set canonical tag

Tags: canonical-link

I used the same header for all pages of the website, how to I set canonical tag for each of the pages

I set the canonical urls of all the pages in the header, I got multiple canonical url conflicts. I have to set each page url in the canonical tag of each page, but i make use of one header for all pages which I import

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.